# What were sideburns called before the Civil War?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, history

According to [reputable sources](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sideburns&searchmode=none), *sideburns* is a corruption of *burnsides*, a reference to the Civil War General Ambrose E. Burnside.

[image]

What was this style of facial hair called before that? I'm referring to **side whiskers and a mustache with a clean-shaven chin**.

Also, is there any difference between the original sideburns and *friendly mutton chops*?

Comment: Search "sideburns" in here, already has an answer

Comment: @Christopher: I found this question, but it distinguishes in meaning between "sideburns," "whiskers" and "muttonchops": http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103437/whiskers-vs-sideburns-usage-in-uk-vs-us-english

Comment: ["sideboards"](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/152687-sideboards-in-BrE) apparently has the same meaning, but I'd guess it is a more recent term derived from "sideburns."

Comment: On Google Ngram there are references to whiskers going back to the 16th century

Comment: another synonym seems to be "[bugger's grips,"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47722/what-is-the-etymology-of-bugger-lugs/48232#48232) but again I don't know how old the term is.

Comment: Where as *side whiskers* only goes back to the 1790's

Comment: Another interesting synonym for sideburns: dundrearies

Answer (score 4):

The style was launched by Gen. Ambrose, so there was apparently no name for it before 1875. ***"Mutton chops"*** or  ***"muttonchop whiskers"*** was used to refer to a similar style:

***[Burnsides](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sideburns%20&searchmode=none):***

> - style of facial hair consisting of side whiskers and a mustache (but clean-shaven chin), ***1875*** (singular; plural form from 1878; many early uses are in college and university magazines), ***a reference to U.S. Army Gen. Ambrose E. Burnside (1824-1881) of Civil War fame, who wore them and inspired the style***. Compare [sideburns](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sideburns&allowed_in_frame=0).
> - ***[Mutton chop](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mutton&allowed_in_frame=0)*** is from 1720; ***as a style of side whiskers, from 1865.***

(Etymonline)

> - Burnside was noted for ***[his unusual facial hair](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrose_Burnside)***, joining strips of hair in front of his ears to his mustache but with chin clean-shaven; ***the word burnsides was coined to describe this style.*** The syllables were later reversed to give sideburns.

(Wikipedia)

[Why sideburns are named as they are](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2013/03/why-sideburns-are-named-as-they-are/):

> - ***It turns out, despite this particular brand of facial hair style being around as far back as at least 100 BC (with one of the earliest known instances being in a mosaic of Alexander the Great), sideburns were named after a specific man in the late 19th century.***
> - ***The man was politician, businessman, and Union Army General, Ambrose Burnside.***  Burnside sported a slightly unusual facial hair style with particularly prominent “mutton chop” sideburns connected to a moustache, while keeping his chin shaved perfectly clean.
> - While an extremely poor General, something he himself was well aware of, ***Burnside’s popularity as a General and later politician, in combination with the fairly unique formation of his whiskers, helped start something of a new facial hair trend.***  Around the 1870s-1880s, this gave rise to this facial hair style being named “burnsides”.
> - ***Within a few years of this, the facial hair down the side of one’s cheeks, rather than being called “mutton chops”*** as it was at the time in some regions, began being called a modification of “burnsides”, “sideburns”, with the first documented instance of this being in 1887.  Presumably the shift was from the fact that this part of the “burnsides” facial hair style was on the sides of the face- and of course, leaving the “burns” part in in homage to the aforementioned style.
> - ***Shortly after “sideburns” popped up***, an alternate “sideboards” also made > - its debut, with “boards” thought to have been shortened from “border”, so essentially “side-boarder”, which is a fitting description of the style.

(www.todayifoundout.com)

[image] ***mutton chops style***

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this really interesting conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32310/discussion-on-answer-by-josh61-what-were-sideburns-called-before-the-civil-war).